# Need only Vertical scrollbars in window.showModalDialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have following code in -

```
function getPopup1(redirectString) {

        var dialog = window.showModalDialog(redirectString , null,
'status:no;dialogWidth:700px;dialogHeight:900px;dialogHide:true;help:no;scroll:1');

    }
```

and the .aspx page has following code, on which I am redirecting-

```
<body style="background-color:White; padding-right:16px; padding-left:16px; width:650px" onload="ScrollData()">
```

I reffered,  Stackoverflow Question  **Show only Vertical scrollbar in ModalDialog window?**

but, it is not working in my case. Can anyone suggest, whats wrong in it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1450847.aspx/1

did you make the div scrollable? i.e.

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100px;height:100px;overflow:auto;"></div>
```

also make sure that you do not have any element (table, div, span) in the the div who's width is greater than the container width + 25px (needed for vertical scroll bar)